# perf undefined symbol: __gcc_personality_v0 matlab

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-16.04, matlab-deployment, perf, matlab-compiler

When I run the following command, I receive error:

```
/usr/lib/linux-tools/4.4.0-66-generic/perf stat -e cycles ./shFile
/usr/lib/linux-tools/4.4.0-66-generic/perf: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libunwind.so.8: undefined symbol: __gcc_personality_v0
```

I would like to use `perf` utility to test `FLOPS` for the MATLAB code. Since `perf` only accept `execute file`, so I used `mcc -m shFile.m` to convert `.sh file` and then used perf command `perf stat -e cycles ./shFile`, it shows the above error. How can I fix this error?

Here's more info:

```
System: Ubuntu 16.4
Matlab: R2016a
perf: 4.4.0-66-generic/perf
```

Comment: Can you show output of `file -k ./shFile` and `ldd ./shFile`? How `mcc` works, is there verbose mode? This is strange that perf can't start process, and as workarund you may try starting the application and using perf with pid of it `./shFile & perf stat -p \`pidof shFile\`` and `./shFile & perf record -p \`pidof shFile\``. You can also try to embed working with hardware counters inside your Matlab code with PAPI (http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/index.html) there should be bindings, something like https://github.com/arm-hpc/papi/blob/master/src/Matlab/PAPI_Matlab.readme & Matlab/flops.readme

Comment: file -k ./shFile
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, stripped\012- data                                                                                                  
ldd ./shFile 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe88da5000)
 libmwlaunchermain.so => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwlaunchermain.so (0x00007f6b6f3fb000)
 libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.0.1 => /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/runtime/glnxa64/libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.0.1 (0x00007f6b6f1b3000)
...